# Getting null value after setting the value of a variable inside observe block

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my UI - MainActivity.kt

I have:

```
private var recommendationCount: Int? = null

onCreate{
   
   viewmodel.recommended.observe(this){
      recommendationCount = it.size
   }
   
   //I need to set the view outside the observe
   binding.myTextView.text = recommendationCount.toString()
   
   //it returns null
  
}
```

When I set my textview outside the observe block, it returns a null value. but when I set it inside, it returns the correct value.

I need to set it outside.

Comment: Move the code from under your observer to inside your observer. The observer is called in the future (possibly immediately after `onCreate()` returns if it has an initial value already), and it is potentially called multiple times. And you shouldn't store a copy of it in a property, because it will be error-prone trying to keep it in sync with the source of truth (the LiveData in your ViewModel).

Comment: The thing is, I have multiple observers that has some values... I need to sum up all these values and set the count in a textview.

Comment: You need to combine them into a single LiveData or Flow by merging them. It can be done with LiveData using MediatorLiveData, but it’s simpler with Flows because you can use the `combine` function. You could do something like `combine(liveDataA.asFlow(), liveDataB.asFlow(), liveDataC.asFlow()) { a, b, c -> a + b + c }.asLiveData()` to avoid having to use coroutines.

Comment: Thanks man, worked! Can you put it as an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to merge the values from multiple LiveData, you need to combine them into a single LiveData. You can't just grab data from each of them sequentially, because LiveData is not intended to work synchronously (you can use the `value` property, but this is not robust because it's possible to check the value before its initial value is set).

You need to combine them into a single LiveData or Flow by merging them. It can be done with LiveData using MediatorLiveData, but it’s easier with Flows because you can use the `combine` function. You could do something like this, converting flows and back to LiveData to avoid having to use coroutines:

```
val combinedLiveData = combine(
        liveDataA.asFlow(), 
        liveDataB.asFlow(), 
        liveDataC.asFlow()
    ) { a, b, c -> 
        a + b + c 
    }.asLiveData()
```

But if you are using coroutines, you wouldn't need to convert back to LiveData.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set it outside the observer simply because the onCreate() executes all the code inside it before the viewModel changes the value of the Observable(Live data, I guess) that you are observing in onCreate()

Comment: The thing is, I have multiple observers that has some values... I need to sum up all these values and set the result of the sum in a textview.